# Replace id by name in the comment without replace wrong case

Tags: php, replace

I have a comment contain mentioned userId like this:

```
$subject = "@1 likes @12 and @123";
```

Now I want to replace these ids with the real name inside an array:

```
$users = [1 => "Henry", 12 => "Tony", 123 => "Pizza"];
```

I got stuck in the situation Henry user can replace all the id contain @1 like this:

```
$subjectReplaced = "@Henry likes @Henry2 and @Henry23"

// What I want is:
$subjectReplaced = "@Henry likes @Tony and @Pizza";
```

Anyone help me, please?

Full code here:

```
<?php

$subject = "@1 likes @12 and @123";
$users = [1 => "Henry", 12 => "Tony", 123 => "Pizza"];

foreach ($users as $id => $user) {
  $subject = str_replace('@' . $id, '@' . $user, $subject);
}

echo $subject;
```

Comment: Show us the code please?

Comment: @AmitMerchant edited, update full code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explode your `subject` based on spaces and do a `preg_match` on each token you receive. If the token  matches your `@some_text` format, we do a replacement in the `subject_data` array below. In the end, we just do an implode() to get the replaced string.

```
<?php

$users = ['1' => "Henry", '12' => "Tony", '123' => "Pizza"];

$subject = "@1 likes @12 and @123";

$subject_data = explode(" ",$subject);

foreach($subject_data as $key => $each_data){
    if(preg_match('/@.+/',$each_data) === 1){
        $subject_data[$key] = "@" . $users[substr($each_data,1)];
    }
}

echo implode(" ",$subject_data);
```

**Note that** this also takes care of overlapping or you can say prefix string issues, like `@1` and `@12`. One of the reasons why I did not use `str_replace()`.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach using the `preg_split` to break the string, then looping through the parts of the breaking string and replacing the ids with the associated user id and finally using `implode` to join the string parts.

```
$subject = "@1 likes @12 and @123";

$users = [1 => "Henry", 12 => "Tony", 123 => "Pizza"];

$parts = preg_split("/(\@\d*)/", $subject, 0, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

foreach ($parts as &$part) {
    if (strpos($part, '@') !== 0) {
        continue;
    }

    $part = $users[substr($part, 1, strlen($part) - 1)] ?? '';
}


$result = implode($parts);

echo $result;
```

**Result:**
Henry likes Tony and Pizza

Test it [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/87c1c051d4e980ac71ba4ffaecdae9b574e31d8b)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_walk` with `str_replace`

```
$subject = "@1 likes @12 and @123";
$patterns = ['1' => 'Henry','12' => 'Tony' ,'123' => 'Pizza'];
$previousKey ='';
array_walk($patterns, function($v, $k) use (&$subject, &$previousKey, $patterns){
    if(!empty($previousKey))
      $subject = str_replace(str_replace($previousKey, $patterns[$previousKey], $k), $v, $subject);
 else
      $subject = str_replace($k, $v, $subject);
$previousKey = $k;
    $previousKey = $k;
});
echo $subject;
```

[Working example](https://3v4l.org/Mjsl4)

Comment: Why have you changed the `$users` completely.

Comment: Not what I want

Comment: @HenryBui answer has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use [`strtr`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) to do the replacements. `strtr` is good for this job because it replaces longer strings first and then won't look at them again so it avoids possible double replacement issues.

```
$subject = "@1 likes @12 and @123";
$users = [1 => "Henry", 12 => "Tony", 123 => "Pizza"];
echo strtr($subject, $users);
```

Output:

```
@Henry likes @Tony and @Pizza
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/4oESQ)

Comment: @HenryBui this is exactly what `strtr` is for. Your answer is a simple one-liner.